# mmap file returns a pointer to an inaccessible place in memory

Tags: c, linux, 64-bit, mmap, read-write

I have this program that is supposed to mmap a file in read-write mode and be able to edit its contents. Also the file this is written for is about 40-50 GB, so I need `mmap64`. The problem is, while `mmap64` does not return an error, the address it returns is not accessible.

```c
#include <assert.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef unsigned long long u64;


void access_test(u64 p, u64 sz)
{
    u64 i;
    char tmp;
    for (i=0; i<sz; i++) {
        tmp = *(char*)(p+i);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd;
    long long int sz, p;
    struct stat buf;

    fd = open(argv[1], O_RDWR, 0x0666);
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("open");
        return 1;
    }

    fstat64(fd, &buf);
    sz = buf.st_size;
    printf("File size: 0x%016llx\n", sz);

    p = mmap64 (0, buf.st_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE , MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if (p == -1) {
        perror ("mmap");
        return 1;
    }

    access_test(p,sz);

    if (close (fd) == -1) {
        perror ("close");
        return 1;
    }


    if (munmap ((void*)p, buf.st_size) == -1) {
        perror ("munmap");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The result of this is on a small file:

```
$ ./testmmap minicom.log

File size: 0x0000000000000023
[1]    8282 segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./testmmap minicom.log
```

The same goes for the big one.

Comment: Don't you need a struct stat64 instead of struct stat?

Comment: On a 64 bits linux system (x86-64 with a 64 bits distro) you don't need `mmap64` ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Always enable warnings when you compile

Here is the result with warnings enabled:

```
$ gcc mmp.c  -Wall -g
mmp.c: In function ‘access_test’:
mmp.c:18:10: warning: variable ‘tmp’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     char tmp;
          ^
mmp.c: In function ‘main’:
mmp.c:36:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘fstat64’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     fstat64(fd, &buf);
     ^
mmp.c:40:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mmap64’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     p = mmap64 (0, buf.st_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE , MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
```

The last two warnings here are extremely important. They say there is no prototype for mmap64. C therefore gives you a default prototype, and it is wrong, at least for the mmap64() call (since the prototype will return an int, which cannot represent a pointer on a 64-bit Linux host)

The argument to fstat64() is a `struct stat64` too BTW, which is another issue.

### Make the specific 64-bit functions available

If you want to make the `fstat64()/mmap64()` function available, you need to compile the code with the _LARGEFILE and LARGEFILE64_SOURCE #define, see information [here](http://users.suse.com/~aj/linux_lfs.html), so you should compile this as e.g:

```
  gcc -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE mmp.c  -Wall -g
```

### Or use #define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64

There is however no need to do this. Just call the normal `fstat()` and `mmap()` and `#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` when compiling. e.g.:

```
   gcc -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 mmp.c  -Wall -g
```

This will enable support for large files, and e.g. translate the mmap() call to mmap64() if it is needed (e.g. if you're on a 32-bit host).

If you are trying to mmap() an 50 GB file, you anyway need to be on a 64-bit host, and on a 64-bit Linux host there's no need for any of this - mmap() and fstat() handles large files without any need to do anything.

### Use pointers

The next issue is you're assigning the return value of `mmap()` to an integer. This might happen to work, but the code does look odd because of it. If you want to treat the thing as a `char *`, assign it to a `char *`. Don't play tricks with casting pointers around to a 64-bit integer type.

E.g. your access function should be:

```
void access_test(char *p, u64 sz)
{
    u64 i;
    char tmp;
    for (i=0; i<sz; i++) {
       tmp = p[i];
    }
}
```

And `p` should be declared as `char *p;` in main(), or use `uint8_t *p;` if you intend to treat the data as binary data.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think that solved it (it will take a while to finish) :D